# Postfix with no auth setup in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp

Now, postfix has been setup by auth. I want to remove user login with username and password. I want to make anonymous SMTP Mail server. What path should I change or what line should I remove ?

my main.cf is following

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

myhostname = smtp.wpecho.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = smtp.wpecho.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
#Use these on Postfix 2.2.x only
#smtp_use_tls = yes
#smtpd_use_tls = yes
#For Postfix 2.3 or above use:
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
always_bcc = admin@homevale.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is already configured to accept authenticated users, users in your networks or known mail addresses (`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`).

So your easiest fix is to add your internal network to the `mynetworks` variable. Something like this should do what you want (assuming that `192.168.x.x` is your internal network). The `/8` means that everything up to the first dot has to be the same and the `/16` means that everything up to the second dot has to be equal to your definition.

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make this accessible over the internet or just in a private LAN? If on the internet: Terrible idea, you will attract tons of spammers in a short time and won't be able to send mails at all shortly after that because you will be blocked by legitimate mail servers.

Comment: yes, I use one web app but they didn't setup for SMTP username and password. I knew the effect and add ip in mynetworks may be best way

Answer (score 0):

You dont say where you want to recieve anonymous mail from, so be careful not to make yourself into an open relay. However `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is what you need to change, and here are the docs for it http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions